# Show DataGrid columns as sum of two classes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` and I would like to show data from two class:

```
[DataContract]
public class File
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<FileRow> radky { get; set; }
}

public class FileRow
{
    public int AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; } }
   //some others variables
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class WebService
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<WSRow> radky { get; set; }
}

public class WSRow
{
    public int AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; } }
    //some others variables
}
```

These two classes provides data in `NAME` and `AMOUNT` variables. Now I need to get data with same `NAME` in both classes, sum theirs `AMOUNT` and show in DataGrid. Is here any way how can achieve that? Should I create new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new class in which you calculate the sum of both object's `amount`variable. Then you can bind a `List<SumOfAmounts>` to the `ItemsSource` property on your DataGrid.

Like this:

SumOfAmounts class :

```
public class SumOfAmounts
{
    private FileRow _fileRow;
    private WSRow _webRow;

    public int Sum { get; set; }

    public SumOfAmounts(FileRow filerow, WSRow webrow)
    {
        _fileRow = filerow;
        _webRow = webrow;

        Sum = _fileRow.AMOUNT + _webRow.AMOUNT;
    }
}
```

In some other class where you'll store all the sums :

```
public class SumStorage
{
    // ...
    public List<SumOfAmounts> Sums { get; set; }
    // ...



    public SumStorage(File file, WebService webSvc)
    {
        Sums = new List<SumOfAmounts>();

        foreach(var row in file.radky)
        {
            var webRow = webSvc.radky.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NAME == row.NAME);
            if(webRow != null)
                Sums.Add(new SumOfAmounts(row, webRow));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the datagrid `ItemsSource` property to the `Sums` property on a `SumStorage` object.

My imagination is pretty limited for class naming but I hope you get the point.
Also, you should respect [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I start write program without any experience with c#... I will try this approach and I will read link you provide.. Later I will mark as accept if it will work, thanks man